# VBA Userforms. Textbox as number value to cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've been searching for a solution to this for a while and have been unsuccessful in finding.  Essentially, I have the user of my document populating fields in a user form that my code then puts into the appropriate cells.  One of these input fields is a number but, no matter how I instruct excel to format the cell, it still is text in the end and I can't perform any calculations.  I'm sure this is probably a pretty simple fix but I've been unsuccessful so far in finding a solution.  As always, any help is appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: How are you writing to the cell? Is it possible that later somewhere in the code you are changing the format of the cell. Please show us the code without which we will be shooting in the dark ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to convert the value from text to a numeric type before putting it into a cell.

Assuming your textbox is called `txtNumber` and you're outputting to cell `Output!A1`, the code would be:

```
Sheets("Output").Range("A1") = CDbl(txtNumber)
```

Other conversion functions you might want to use are `CLng` (convert to Long), `CInt` (convert to Integer), `CDec` (convert to decimal, useful for currency values).

This code will raise an error if the user types a non-numeric text value into the field. You should validate on the textbox's Change event and disable the OK button if invalid data is inputted.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much.  Can't believe that was so easy. The pains of being a self-taught coder.  I'll accept your answer in just a few.  SOF is making me wait four more minutes.